# Out as an argument or use return value

Tags: c

In functions, is there best to use return value or out argument? Is one way preferable over the other one? In C.

vec_t is a struct (typedef):

```
typedef struct {
    float   x, y, z;
} vec_t;
```

.

```
void multiply_vectors(vec_t* v1, vec_t* v2, vec_t* out) {
    ...
}

vec_t result;
multiply_vectors(&first, &second, &result);
```

or

```
vec_t multiply_vectors(vec_t* v1, vec_t* v2) {
    vec_t v;
    ...
    return v;
}

vec_t result = multiply_vectors(&first, &second);
```

Comment: There are no `out`-arguments, but pointers you pass, these serve an equal purpose, though

Answer (score 3):

*It depends* mostly on personal preference. I normally go with an actual return value, and if there's a case I need multiply return values, I may use out arguments or if it makes sense, create a struct with all return values in I can return normally.

I find out args to be confusing, especially because you get involved with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one right answer.  Your first consideration should be what *makes sense* for that particular operation.  In your example, returning the new vector as a return value as opposed to an output parameter *makes sense*, as it's a mathematical operation.  However, when you look at library functions like `scanf`, they use output parameters for values and return a "status" value.  Again, for how `scanf` typically is used, this *makes sense*.

However, there can be other considerations.  Note that you're creating a "temporary" vector in the body of the function, which takes up space on the stack, and when the function returns, the contents of that vector must be copied to your target.  In this case, it's not worth worrying about, but if you're dealing with *very large* items, it *may* have a negative impact on performance.  In cases like that, you may be better off using an output parameter and passing a pointer to the target.

The problem's a little worse in C++ when you're dealing with constructors and destructors, and a simple return winds up executing a lot of code under the hood.  Again, start with what *makes sense*, but if you find yourself running into performance issues, you may have to use an alternate method.